Firefox generating two sessions in PHP
I am trying to record session ID's in Mysql database using PHP. In firefox, when I load a page, it records two different session ID's at the same time. However, in Chrome it only generates a single session ID and record only once. Does Firefox behave differently when it comes to generating session ID's? Not sure why it could be generating two sessions in Firefox but not in Chrome?
In my application I have a header template that loads on every page and this header template has session_start() declared at the top. I am not generating any new sessions or any new session ID's throughout the application.

How do you "record session ID"? Where are the HTTP headers for the request(s)? What do your log files tell you? Browsers DO NOT generate session IDs (at least not in any way visible to you). How are your PHP sessions configured? Even if you called session_start() multiple times from your PHP code it would not generate a new (PHP) session id.

Furthermore session id's just a random number; why is it a problem if firefox fires of two separate requests, as long as the user session is maintained properly?
